Does 'twice' rhyme with 'improvised'?

Nothing can ever happen twice.
In consequence, the sorry fact is
that we arrive here improvised
and leave without the chance to practise.

The above is the opening stanza of the poem'Nothing Twice' by Wislawa Szymborska. The Rhyme Scheme of the poem is said to be ABAB. Does 'twice' rhyme with 'improvised'? Are these two words rhyming words? What about the '-ed' of 'improvised'? Would someone clarify my doubts? Thanks in advance.

I'll answer the most important question for a learner, which was perhaps implied but not stated: "Should I pronounce 'twice' and 'improvised' the same? No, you shouldn't. Pronunciations vary regionally, but in general the "d" in "improvised" will be enunciated, "twice" will have a sibilant "s" sound, and "improvise" will have more of a "z" sound.
Now to the question "Is it ok to use them for lines of poetry that are meant to rhyme?" That's a literary question. But yes, imperfect rhymes are often used. There are some unusual usages here (people are not normally "improvised"), but poetry allows us to use language in unusual ways for artistic effect. It looks like Szymborska published this poem in a volume that had "Polish and English on facing pages," so some unusual rhymes or usages might also come from the challenge of trying to translate while preserving poetic qualities.

Do you pronounce the final vowel sound of both words the same?  In my dialect, (PNW English) twice has something like [ʌɪs], whereas improvise would have [aɪz].  I don't consider those rhymes, even ignoring the voiced/unvoiced sibilant.

@Juhasz - This chart (which admittedly says it's for RP and 'similar accents') gives price for [aɪ]. Would you consider that a rhyme for twice?

@Juhasz I couldn't say if there's a difference in quality, but my vowel in "twice" is less than half as long as the vowel in "improvised", which is a pretty jarring contrast.

@KateBunting, price and twice do rhyme for me, but I don't think I use [aɪ] for those words.  I'd use that diphthong for prize, though.  I'm now remembering that this feature of my dialect is described either as Canadian Raising, or sometimes American Raising (because it only affects /aɪ/, not /aʊ/ ).  It's not that common in West Coast dialects, but is present in PNW perhaps because of the large number of migrants form the Upper Midwest.

price and prize don't rhyme.  Rhymes in that sort of humorous Ogden Nashian poetry are often playful and intentionally depart from the strict.

Presumably lines 2 and 4 with 'is' and 'practise' are supposed to rhyme, but the meter is all over the place too.

@Andy Bonner, from your answer, I believe 'twice - improvised' is an example of imperfect rhyme, at least to those who pronounce the final 'd' inaudibly. Thank you for your answer and those who commented. +1

I’ve upvoted. And pronunciations do indeed vary. In mine (American mid-Atlantic), @Juhasz, the vowel depends whether the following consonant is voiced. This is called Canadian raising. For example, for each of write (ride), tight (tide), and strife (strive), in the first word my vowel is a diphthong starting with the vowel of up, and the second have the diphthong starting with the vowel of Bach.

Not sure if I read this correctly, but BrE does not spell 'improvise' with a 'z'

@Smock Oops, you're right; that's embarrassing
